# Driver not found error when using examples with Qt 4.7 and QVFb?

Tags: qt4, embedded-linux

I'm trying to get started with embedded linux Qt Development, and I've built Qt for embedded linux, and built QVFb but when I launch any of the example programs I get an error that a driver isn't found.

```
./analogclock -qws -display QVFb:0
QVFb: driver not found
```

Any idea what I've done wrong?  Do I need to configure Qt for embedded and QVFb at the same time and rebuild everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you qt configured with

```
-plugin-gfx-qvfb
```

option?

Comment: Thanks, I had figured it out before but forgot to come back and answer my own question.